# React Native Image Picker

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I want to use the React Native Image Picker I saw (here's the link https://github.com/marcshilling/react-native-image-picker/blob/master/README.md )

In step 3, what does the documentation mean by "Make sure you have 'Create Groups' selected" ?

Also, "Make sure UIImagePickerManager.m is listed under 'Compile Sources' in your project's 'Build Phases' tab"
How can I add the UIImagePickerManager.m in Build Phases, because when I try to add the file, I can only the pick the folder where the is located, not the exact file.

Comment: You don't need to do this if you run **react-native link react-native image-picker** command

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question: In Xcode when you add files that are in existing Groups (what Xcode calls folders because they're separate from actual file structures) you can create the groups you are missing automatically by checking a box in the [dialog that is labeled "Create Groups" or something similar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWQKI.png). However, I don't think adding the folder to your library will prompt you in that way.

Second question: You could simply drag that single file out of the library and into your Compile Sources. At this point it might prompt you with a dialog that does include "Create Groups" as an option.